# Web service not sychronizing correctly - Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am building an `Android` application which synchronizes my incidents (values from `SQlite`database and a corresponding screen shot image) and posts the data to my web server.

First of all I select the incidents to be synchronized by using checkboxes and then post the selected incidents and images to the web server using an asynchronous task for each incident .

By problem is that if I have two incidents, the same incident is posted twice.

```
    package com.softwareconcepts.incidentmanager;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Set;

    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Base64;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.CheckBox;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
    import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
    import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;
    import com.softwareconcepts.incidentmanager.constants.Constants;
    import com.softwareconcepts.incidentmanager.model.Incident;

    public class SynchronizeIncidentsActivity extends Activity {
        private List<Incident> allIncidentsList = new ArrayList<Incident>();
        private  Set<Incident> selectedIncidentsSet = new HashSet<Incident>();
        private static final String LOG_TAG = "SynchronizeIncidentsActivity";
        private Incident currentIncident;
        private byte [] imageByteArray;

        private ProgressDialog prgDialog;
        private String encodedString;
        private RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        private String fileName;

        MyCustomAdapter dataAdapter = null;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_synchronize_incidents);
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            prgDialog.setCancelable(false);
            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            allIncidentsList = bundle.getParcelableArrayList(".model.Incident");
            displayListView();
            addIncidentsToSynchronize();
        }


        private void displayListView() {
            dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this,
                    R.layout.incident_info, allIncidentsList);
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    Incident incident = (Incident) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Clicked on Row: " + incident.getDescription(), 
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

        }

        private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Incident> {
            private ArrayList<Incident> incidentsList;

            public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, 
                    List<Incident> incidentsList) {
                super(context, textViewResourceId, incidentsList);
                this.incidentsList = new ArrayList<Incident>();
                this.incidentsList.addAll(incidentsList);
            }
            private class ViewHolder {
                TextView clientIdTextView;
                CheckBox descriptionCheckBox;
            }
            @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                ViewHolder holder = null;
                Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));
                if (convertView == null) {
                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(
                            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.incident_info, null);

                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.clientIdTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
                    holder.descriptionCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check_box);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);

                    holder.descriptionCheckBox.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {  
                        public void onClick(View v) {  
                            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ;  
                            Incident incident = (Incident) cb.getTag();
                            if (cb.isChecked()) {
                                selectedIncidentsSet.add(incident);
                                incident.setSelected(true);
                            } else {
                                if(selectedIncidentsSet.contains(incident)) {
                                    selectedIncidentsSet.remove(incident);
                                }
                            }
                        }  
                    });  
                } 
                else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }

                Incident incident = incidentsList.get(position);
                holder.clientIdTextView.setText(" (" +  incident.getClientId() + ")");
                holder.descriptionCheckBox.setText(incident.getDescription());
                holder.descriptionCheckBox.setChecked(incident.isSelected());
                holder.descriptionCheckBox.setTag(incident);
                return convertView;
            }
        }

        private void addIncidentsToSynchronize() {
            Button synchronizeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findSelected);
            synchronizeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    for (Incident incident : selectedIncidentsSet) {
                        if (incident.isSelected()) {
                            currentIncident = incident;
                            synchronizeData();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        private void refreshActivity() {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            startActivity(intent);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "The main activity has been refreshed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


        public void synchronizeData() {
            prgDialog.setMessage("Synchronizing data to web server.");
            prgDialog.show();
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    imageByteArray = currentIncident.getImageByteArray();
                    fileName = currentIncident.getImagePath();
                    params.put("filename", fileName);
                    params.put("description", currentIncident.getDescription());
                    params.put("agentId", currentIncident.getAgentId());
                    params.put("clientId", currentIncident.getClientId());
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "currentIncident being synchronized: " + currentIncident.getId());
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "currentIncident description being synchronized: " + currentIncident.getDescription());

                };

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(imageByteArray, 0);
                    return "";
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                    prgDialog.setMessage("Calling Upload");
                    params.put("image", encodedString);
                    triggerImageUpload();
                }
            }.execute(null, null, null);
        }

        public void triggerImageUpload() {
            makeHTTPCall();
        }

        public void makeHTTPCall() {
            prgDialog.setMessage("Invoking the Web Service for file incident upload");      
            AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "The incident decription being posted: " + params.toString());
            client.post(Constants.IMAGE_UPLOAD_SERVLET_URL,
                    params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String response) {
                    prgDialog.hide();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error,
                        String content) {
                    prgDialog.hide();
                    if (statusCode == 404) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Requested resource not found.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else if (statusCode == 500) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Something went wrong at server end.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "Error Occured \n Most Common Error: \n"
                                        + "1. Device not connected to Internet\n"
                                        + "2. Web App is not deployed in App server\n"
                                        + "3. App server is not running\n HTTP Status code : "
                                        + statusCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                        .show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            if (prgDialog != null) {
                prgDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

    }
```